# How to group results from a column together

Tags: sql, databricks

so... i want to find out the top 5 customers that spent the most on 1992 Ferrari 360 Spider red from my dataset

This is the query responding to the question above:

```
select C.customerNumber, C.customerName, P.productName, sum(ODF.priceEach) from orderDetailFacts ODF
left join Customers C on ODF.customerNumber = C.customerNumber
left join Products P on ODF.productCode = P.productCode
where P.productName like '%1992 Ferrari%'
group by C.customerNumber, C.customerName, P.productName, ODF.priceEach
order by sum(ODF.priceEach) desc
limit 5
```

The result that i got back is: [[https://i.stack.imgur.com/rowRY.png]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGbRg.png) (There are more results than the screenshot)

However, the problem i have is that i am unable to group for e.g Mini Gifts Distributors Ltd(row 5 and 6) from the customerName column together so that the priceEach column will be the sum.

So it means that row 5 and 6 will be joined together and the priceEach column will be 386.09 instead of 196.43 and 189.66 separately.

Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want one row per *customer*/*product*.  But you are including the price as well.  So, fix the `GROUP BY`:

```
select C.customerNumber, C.customerName, P.productName, sum(ODF.priceEach)
from orderDetailFacts ODF join
     Customers C
     on ODF.customerNumber = C.customerNumber join
     Products P
     on ODF.productCode = P.productCode
where P.productName like '%1992 Ferrari%'
group by C.customerNumber, C.customerName, P.productName;
```

Note the changes:

- `ODF.priceEach` is removed from the `GROUP BY`.
- You are requiring matches between the tables, so `LEFT JOIN` is not appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `ODF.priceEach` from group by clause since you are aggregating this column

```
select C.customerNumber, C.customerName, P.productName, sum(ODF.priceEach) from orderDetailFacts ODF
left join Customers C on ODF.customerNumber = C.customerNumber
left join Products P on ODF.productCode = P.productCode
where P.productName like '%1992 Ferrari%'
group by C.customerNumber, C.customerName, P.productName
```